# Sending throught socket python, threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I wanted try something, and it doesnt work. I want make client socket thread, and then send some message anytime, when I call. I wanted do this by command `client.sock.sendall(data)` but its doesnt work. Why? First I called my client instance, then socket, and then command to send data.. My client thread should live, so i can call him anytime.. right?

here is my client code:

```
 import threading
 import socket
 import pickle

 def main():

      class Chat_Client(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.host = '127.0.0.1'
                self.sock = None
                self.running = 1
            def run(self):
                PORT = 1234
                self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.sock.connect((self.host, PORT))

            def kill(self):
                self.running = 0

      client=Chat_Client()
      client.start()

      pole=['majo','jojo', 'surovec']
      data = pickle.dumps(pole)
      client.sock.sendall(data)

      client.kill()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

And here is error message:

```
    client.sock.sendall(data)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Does some way exist, how to make it? I am beginer, and I'm trying learning python..

Best Regards

Jozef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
while client.sock is None:
  time.sleep(0.0001)

client.sock.sendall(data)
```

You would be better off using a `Queue` though.

Comment: Thanks, its working. But it printed error: client.sock.sendall(data)
OSError: [WinError 10057]. But data were send, and received too. So I will probably try Queue